# Global Entry U.S. mailing address

Tags: global-entry, trusted-traveler, sentri

I am trying to figure out what is the best TTP Program to apply for my inlaws who travel frequently with us. We are US citizens, already registered withGlobal Entry, but they are  Mexican Nationals with a valid tourist visa. The choices are either SENTRI or GE.

I know both share the same benefits and are basically the same regarding those (TSA Pre / access to SENTRI lanes, kiosks, etc) but I saw that GE has faster processing time and seems cheaper. Mexico is part of the country that qualify for GE.

Do they have to have a US mailing address for the GE card to be mailed to them? Or can it be sent to their Mexican address? It's important to have the GE card because we live in San Diego and having access to those SENTRI lines would be nice.

I've been trying to find the answer on the CBP website but there is nothing conclusive, so if someone had their GE cards mailed to an non-US address please let me know.

Thanks!

UPDATE: Started filling the application, at some point it requires you to enter an US contact address who can can receive mail for you. Guess that answers that :)

Comment: Personally I don't trust anything to be delivered in Mexico. Only thing I'd trust is to have it sent to DHL and have it collected from there (I've done this once before, for passports). I use a San Diego address for everything even though I live in Tijuana.

Comment: I understand that most non-US citizen/LPR Global Entry members aren't given a card (the card isn't used for air travel and I guess most non-US members don't get the land border benefit), so you'll want to check that Mexicans do get a GE card if use of SENTRI lanes is important. A SENTRI membership does come with a card to allow use of the lanes. A NEXUS membership also comes with a card, though the interview locations are likely inconvenient.

Comment: [Mexican nationals do get a card](https://www.cbp.gov/travel/trusted-traveler-programs/global-entry/card), but I can't find anything that explicitly confirms they'll send one to a Mexican address.

Comment: Started filling the application, at some point it requires you to enter an US contact address who can can receive mail for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well i ended up finding out one i started filling up their app. It turns out it requires you enter an US contact that can receive mail in their behalf since they only mail the card to US addresses.

Comment: Do you know if you could have mailed the cards to them to their Mexico addresses?

Comment: CBP will only mail it to an US address.  I suppose you can always send it via DHL or a trusted delivery service to them once you received it as someone posted above.  I didn't have to, since they just picked it up next time they came to visit.